# How do I handle a Win32Com Save() function saving to a completely random file?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

The question outlines the basis of my problem. I’m calling Save() upon a workbook, but instead of saving to the pre-existing file, it instead reverts to the first instance of the file, while creating a separate file entirely.

```
workbook01.Save()
```

Upon running the code, no exception is thrown, but the original file neglects to update. Instead, a completely new, randomly named file appears, prompting me to save it. This contains the updated Excel workbook.

I haven’t had this happen before regarding this program, so I am uncertain what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Simply switched to SaveAs and removed the intermediary file.